# Run cp command by specifying java version

Tags: java, linux, javac

I have JDK 1.8 installed in my Linux server.
I want to deploy my Spring boot application that runs on JDK 11 to Linux server.
I cannot upgrade JDK version of my Linux server since there are other application running on the same Linux server and i don't want to disturb them.

For this reason i have Zipped JDK 11, copied it to Linux Server in a folder specific to my application(same place where my spring boot application jar resides) and un-zipped it.

I tried to start my application with the following command but it still runs JDK 1.8 by default and throws exception

```
java -cp test-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.test.api.TestAPIApplication
```

How can i modify the above Linux command to make my application run on JDK 11

I cannot modify java path since it will affect other applications on same Linux server.

Comment: Just specificy the path on the command line `/wherever/java11/is/bin/java -cp ...`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, Tried giving path but it is not recognising the file: Getting below error 
jdk-11.0.10/bin/java: not found [No such file or directory]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't:

- You can't tweak the Java version via the `-cp` option.
- You can't run a Java version that is not installed.

If you want to run a SpringBoot application that has dependencies on Java 11 (or later) features or APIs, then you must install Java 11 (or later).

The Java 11 libraries are compiled with to Java 11 classfile format.  A Java 8 JVM won't understand them.  Furthermore, the libraries (most likely) depend on native code methods (and other things) that are only available in a Java 11 (or later) `java` executable.  This means that your idea of not installing Java 11 is technically infeasible.

But what you can do is install Java 11 alongside Java 8 on your server, and then select the version of Java you use either by using an absolute pathname for the `java` command or setting the `PATH` environment variable appropriately.

(On a typical Linux system, the package names for Java 8 and Java 11 are different.  So there should be no difficulty installing either versions, or having both versions installed at the same time.  Likewise, the Oracle Java installers install into different Java versions into different directories.)

(Likewise, environment variable settings are NOT shared in Linux.  So you can set them differently for different applications.  If you make the `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME` or whatever changes in the appropriate places, your new Java 11 application won't interfere with existing Java 8 apps.  It is just "basic shell stuff".)